# Entity mapped by other many different Entities (with Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, mapping

I know my title is not clear, but I don't know how to explain my question with few words.

I have two classes with a bidirectional mapping. `Image.class`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
public class Image{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Father.class)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name="father")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 11)
    Father father;

}
```

and `Father.class`:

```
class Father{

      @Id
      @Column(name = "id")
      @GeneratedValue
      Long id;

      @OneToOne(mappedBy = "father")  
      Image pic;
}
```

Now, I'd like to use `Image.class` as field of other classes. Let's say I have `Mother.class`

```
 class Mother{

          @Id
          @Column(name = "id")
          @GeneratedValue
          Long id;

          @OneToOne(mappedBy = "mother")  
          Image pic;
    }
```

My question is: how should I edit the "mapping" of `Image.class`?

Of course `Image.class` cannot have a field like `Father father`, since in the last scenario `Image.class` is a field of `Mother.class` and is not a field of `Father.class`.

I remember that there was I way that allow you to save, in a single table, an `Entity` that can be mapped by many different `Entities`. I remember that I needed to add a field in the table that distinguishes wheter `Image.class` is "bound" to `Father.class` or `Mother.class`.

I'm no more able to find that documentation on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that "field" is not the right term to describe a relation. `Father` and `Mother` would have a *relation* to `Image` and this could be unidirectional, i.e. `Image` wouldn't know which entity it belongs to.

This probably is the most sensible way to go and if there are no good reasons to require a bidirectional relation I'd suggest you go the unidirectional route. To make the relation unidirectional you'd have to make `Mother` and `Father` the owning side, i.e. put the image id into their tables and remove the `mappedby` from their `@OneToOne` while removing the mapping from `Image` entirely.

If you *really* need to know that and need Hibernate to be able to navigate the relation then you'd have to use a common super class (also needs to be an entity even if there are no instances) and probably table-per-class inheritance.

Besides that you could store information about who is related to the image in `Image` itself and do the lookup manually.